# How can one pass attribute values during the chef-client run command

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have the following attributes defined in the attribute file

---

```
node.default['main']['a2'] = "hello world"
```

---

In my recipe i have it being called in the following way

## Recipe:: default

## Copyright (c) 2018 The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

execute 'just_test' do 
command 'touch /tmp/a2345' 
end 
execute 'just_test1' do 
command "touch #{/tmp/node['main']['a2']}" 
end 
execute 'just_test2' do 
command "echo #{node['main']['a2']}" 
end

I would like to pass the value of the attribute during run time, By default it will be "hello world: and it will create a directory with the name hello world,

How can i change the attribute values during the chef-client run on a node instance??? to a different value from "hello world" to "chef deploy"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via the json passed into the `-j` argument to the command line.  This is highly discouraged.  It will cause a permanent normal attribute to be created and associated with the node, which becomes difficult to maintain and debug.

You want to setup a role or a role cookbook which is in the run_list of the node, or else apply a compiled policyfile to the node.  Assign it at the 'default' or 'override' level (and *NOT* the 'normal' level).

If you're trying to test out your cookbook, you should look into test-kitchen which supports setting attributes via the .kitchen.yml file which can then be used to spin up a fresh, clean virt, install chef and compile your recipe code and letting you fiddle with the attributes.

Comment: Is there some sample file that you could provide for review??

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attribute in a [role](https://docs.chef.io/roles.html) which will have higher [precedence](https://docs.chef.io/_images/overview_chef_attributes_table.png) than that set in cookbook. You can pass the attribute as a json file during runtime using -j option also but like mentioned in above answer it will be set as a normal attribute and it will be converged to the node at the end of successful run.

You can create the json file like myattributes.json

```
{ "main": {
          "a2": "chef deploy"
          }
}
```

Run `chef-client -j myattributes.json`